# Qt add menuBar, menus, and sub menus to QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qmenubar

I have a hard time adding menu Bar, menus and sub menus to Qt QMainWindow programmatically.

The following code produces an error:

**QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QMainWindow "", which already has a layout**

Notes :
*.The main window come out without any menu or Layout (Empty!)

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QApplication>
#include<QSlider>
#include<QSpinBox>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QWidget>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include<QMenuBar>
#include<QStatusBar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar;
            QMenu *file = new QMenu();
            file->addMenu("&File");
            menu->addMenu(file);

            QSlider *s1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
               QSlider *s2 = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
               QSpinBox *sb = new QSpinBox;


               QHBoxLayout *L = new QHBoxLayout;
                L->addWidget(s1);
                L->addWidget(s2);
                L->addWidget(sb);




     QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;
     w->setLayout(L);
     w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, i used to create menus using QT designer which was really easy and fast. However, I will soon have an exam which could ask to write the code on paper!

if there is any easier way to do it ,please let me know.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the layout of the `QMainWindow`?  What are you actually trying to achieve?  If you want to implement certain functionality within the context of a `QMainWindow` you would generally implement that functionality in a class derived from `QWidget` and then pass a pointer to an instance of that class to [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @G.M. thank you, I already solve the problem. just to clarify, I used to use QWidget instead of  QMainWindow and it was working but I couldn't add a menuBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add layout to central widget:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QApplication>
#include<QSlider>
#include<QSpinBox>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QWidget>

#include<QMenuBar>
#include<QStatusBar>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;

    QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar;
    QMenu *file = new QMenu();
    file->addMenu("&File");
    menu->addMenu(file);

    QWidget *centralwidget = new QWidget(w);
    w->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);

    QSlider *s1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, centralwidget);
    QSlider *s2 = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical, centralwidget);
    QSpinBox *sb = new QSpinBox;


    QHBoxLayout *L = new QHBoxLayout(centralwidget);
    L->addWidget(s1);
    L->addWidget(s2);
    L->addWidget(sb);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This example doesn't successfully actually add the menu to the window.

Answer (score 2):

Each `QMainWindow` should have a central widget:

```
QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;

QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget;
w->setCentralWidget( centralWidget );

centralWidget->setLayout(L);
w->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final version

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QApplication>
#include<QSlider>
#include<QSpinBox>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QWidget>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include<QMenuBar>
#include<QStatusBar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);


            QSlider *s1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
               QSlider *s2 = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
               QSpinBox *sb = new QSpinBox;


     QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;

     QWidget *cw = new QWidget(w);

     QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar(cw);


     QHBoxLayout *L = new QHBoxLayout(cw);
      L->addWidget(s1);
      L->addWidget(s2);
      L->addWidget(sb);

             QMenu *file = new QMenu("&File");
             file->addMenu("Open");
              file->addMenu("new");

              QMenu *Build = new QMenu("&Build");
              Build->addAction("Rebuild this file");
               Build->addAction("Rebuild All");

             menu->addMenu(file);
             menu->addMenu(Build);

    w->setCentralWidget(cw);

     w->show();


     QObject::connect  (s1,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  sb,SLOT(setValue(int) )   );
     QObject::connect  (s1,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  s2,SLOT(setValue(int) )   );

     QObject::connect  (s2,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  sb,SLOT(setValue(int) )   );
     QObject::connect  (s2,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  s1,SLOT(setValue(int) )   );

     QObject::connect  (sb,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  s1,SLOT(setValue(int) )    );
     QObject::connect  (sb,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ),  s2,SLOT(setValue(int) )    );

     return a.exec();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To try to clearly answer the question suggested by the title (which is not a question by itself), `QMainWindow` does already have an empty menu bar by default besides other things like a central widget.

To access this `QMenuBar` and populate it with things of your choice, just call `menuBar()` from your `QMainWindow` instance.
To add a submenu to a `QMenuBar`, use `QMenuBar::addMenu`.

For example :

```
QAction* newAct = new QAction("save");
auto fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
auto submenu = fileMenu->addMenu("Submenu");
submenu->addAction(new QAction("action1");
submenu->addAction(new QAction("action2");
```

For more information, look at this Qt example : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html and also the `QMenuBar` reference https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#details

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an ancient post  , but the answers are unnecessary complicated

basic  Qt Widget application

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;

w.menuBar()->addAction("TEST");

w.show();
```

plus

```
     addAction("TEST"); 

     has 4 overloads to actually implement the menu option
```

Comment: not an issue brother, but I think i need to close this question. I stopped programming in QT for a while. btw, i wrote the answer which worked for me before. Not to mention i cannot test if your solution works. Anyway, super thanks bro.